# How can I obtain the eigenvalues of this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues

Consider the following $M \times 3$ matrix
$$\mathbf F = [\mathbf h_1, \mathbf h_2, \mathbf h_3],$$
with distinct non-zero singular values $\sigma_1 >\sigma_2 > \sigma_3$, where  $\mathbf h_k$'s are $M \times 1$ vector.
Then, we can easily see that matrix $\mathbf F \mathbf F^H$ has distinct non-zero eigenvalues $\sigma_1^2 > \sigma_2^2 > \sigma_3^2$.
My question is how can I obtain the eigenvalues of
$$\mathbf G = \mathbf F \mathbf F_2^H$$
where $\mathbf F_2 = [\mathbf h_1, -\mathbf h_2, -\mathbf h_3]$. Here, $\mathbf F_2$ has same singular values of $\mathbf F$. Note that it can be also expressed as
$$\mathbf G = \mathbf F \mathbf F_2^H = \mathbf F (\mathbf F \mathbf D)^H = \mathbf F \mathbf D \mathbf F^H,$$ where $\mathbf D = \mathrm{diag}([1, -1, -1])$.
Or at least $\mathbf G$ has distinct eigenvalues?

Any comments or suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The three nonzero eigenvalues of the $M\times M$ matrix $G=FF_2^H$ are the same as the eigenvalues of the $3\times 3$ matrix $G'=F_2^HF$. The matrix elements of $G'$ are
$$G'=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 h_1\cdot h_1 & h_1\cdot h_3 & h_1\cdot h_3 \\
 -h_1\cdot h_3 & -h_2\cdot h_2 & -h_2\cdot h_3 \\
 -h_1\cdot h_3 & -h_2\cdot h_3 & -h_3\cdot h_3 \\
\end{array}
\right).$$
So the eigenvalues are the roots $\lambda$ of
$$(\lambda-h_1\cdot h_1) \left((h_2\cdot h_2+\lambda) (h_3\cdot h_3+\lambda)-(h_2\cdot h_3)^2\right)+(h_1\cdot h_2)^2 (h_3\cdot h_3+\lambda)-2 (h_1\cdot h_2 )(h_1\cdot h_3) (h_2\cdot h_3)+(h_1\cdot h_3)^2 (h_2\cdot h_2+\lambda)=0.$$
This cubic equation has a closed-form solution, but it's lengthy and not particularly instructive.